# Amcharts show balloon on click

Tags: amcharts, ammap, balloon-tip

I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to get amcharts to show balloons not on rollover, but on click of a map marker.  I have links I want to show in the balloon, so want it to stay visible when I move the cursor off of the map marker.  I have been able to capture the click of the marker with this:

```
map.addListener("clickMapObject", function() { //... });
```

Other than [extracting the data from the balloon and showing it in another element](http://www.amcharts.com/tips/displaying-rollover-balloon-outside-chart-area/), I've seen no examples of how to invoke the balloon itself programatically.  I want to use the balloon because it's positioned correctly near the map object you click.

Comment: There's no way to do that using amCharts built-in functions, I'm afraid.

Comment: Wouldn't this seem like a good behavior to add? If you have a link in the balloon, there's no way to click it because the balloon disappears as soon as you move off of the marker...

Comment: Agreed. Would you consider using description box? If map image has a `description` property, it will open up as a description box when you click on that image.